# Finding #temp table in sysobjects / INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running a `SELECT INTO` statement like this so I can manipulate the data before finally dropping the table.

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC INTO #preop FROM tblRANDOM
```

However when I run the statement and then, without dropping the newly created table, I then run either of the following statements, the table isn't found? Even scanning through object explorer I can't see it. Where should I be looking?

```
SELECT [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [name] = N'#preop'
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '#preop'
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Temp tables aren't stored in the local database, they're stored in `tempdb`. Also their name isn't what you named them; it has a hex code suffix and a bunch of underscores to disambiguate between sessions. And you should use [`sys.objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190324(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) or [`sys.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187406(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), not the [deprecated `sysobjects` (note the big warning at the top)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) or [the incomplete and stale `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

The following query will show that if you have multiple sessions with the same #temp table name (`#preop`), they show up in the metadata with distinct names, and the name is not just `#preop`. To be crystal clear, this is not how to find the `object_id` for this specific #temp table in your session, it will also return others. Again, to avoid any confusion, I never intended anyone to expect this is a safe query for finding a #temp table in your session named `#preop`. It is merely demonstrating why there isn't a table named `#preop` in `tempdb.sys.objects`:

```
SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.objects WHERE name LIKE N'#preop[_]%';
```

If you are trying to determine if such an object exists *in your session*, so that you know if you should drop it first, you should do:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#preop') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #preop;
END
```

In modern versions (SQL Server 2016+), this is even easier:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #preop;
```

However if this code is in a stored procedure then there really isn't any need to do that... the table should be dropped automatically when the stored procedure goes out of scope.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand - Thanks - that's useful to know

Comment: Aaron Bertrand - so this should work at the start of a stored procedure but doesn't due to a permissions error? 

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.objects WHERE name LIKE N'#preop[_]%')
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE #preop
END

The error is:

Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 3
Cannot drop the table '#preop', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. 

Sorry this looks rubbish, but how do you code comments?

Comment: @Paul you don't. You update the question to include all of the problem you're trying to solve. The question right now asks how to find an object, not try to drop it.

Comment: @PaulStevens you can use `\`backticks\`` in comments... but yeah, don't. It's best to keep those for stray `identifiers` or whatever - not for whole snippets.

Comment: Using `OBJECT_ID` seems safer to me than `LIKE` as it sorts out simultaneous sessions using the same temp table name, no?

Comment: @Charlieface This is almost 10 years old, but the first query just shows how to identify the table names that are created with that naming pattern (your session's and, possibly, others'). Nowhere did I suggest it was a safe way to identify _just yours_.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer to query `tempdb` in such manner:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.objects 
             WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.[dbo].[#MyProcedure]')
             AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN 
    print 'dropping [dbo].[#MyProcedure]'
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[#MyProcedure]
END
GO
```

Comment: The use of the `OBJECT_ID` function and the friendly name is more specific than using a `LIKE` predicate. The missing piece for me was the `[tempdb]` database _before_ `[dbo]` in the `OBJECT_ID` function.

Comment: @gregsonian The `LIKE` predicate I demonstrated in my answer was not meant to show how to find _your copy of the #temp table_. It was demonstrating why there isn't a table in `tempdb.sys.objects` called `#preop`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is how I got the columns for a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (PK INT IDENTITY(1,1), APP_KEY INT PRIMARY KEY)

SELECT * FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE c.TABLE_NAME LIKE '#T%'
```